# Why is Apache flink class loading not resolving classes in uber jar during class loading?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

When using Apache Beam flink runner I get the following errors. Unless the Beam libraries are added in /lib directory the errors continues to be there when querying metrics. Help appreciated

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/runners/core/metrics/ShortIdMap
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1643)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:520)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.runners.core.metrics.ShortIdMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:60)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: So if you install the libraries the error won't show?

Comment: If we manually copy the library to the flink lib it works , but adding it to the jobmanager lib artifacts it fails . I was wondering if classloading does not look into user ubser jar artifacts to resolve !

Comment: You should edit this comment into your question at the top, that's really the key point!